# Cannot run bundle install due to dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I recently installed [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) and I believe at some point during install it screwed up my environment.  My app is relatively old and I am running Rails -v 4.2.2 and Ruby -v 2.2.3.

When I run `bundle install` it gets pretty far and fails at:

```
The latest bundler is 2.0.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
To update, run `gem install bundler`
Downloading rails-4.2.2 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile (bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)).
Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update rails` should fix the problem.
```

The message doesn't make sense to me because I am using -v 1.15 which is < 2.0 and >= 1.3.  I've also ran the command with `--full-index` and there was no change.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try `gem update bundler` instead of `gem install bundler`.

Comment: It attempts to install -v 2.0.1 which will not work with my ruby version

Comment: Maybe `bundle _1.15.2_ install`?

Comment: Are you using rvm?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what I did, but I shuffles around my gemsets and it seemed to work?  Something about installing RubyMine messed with some PATH variables